# Python Requests Post is Stuck at Starting New HTTP Connection

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

```
user_info = json.dumps({"bio":biography, "interests":interest_indexes})
headers = {'Content-type':'application/json'}
url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/" + str(user_id)
r = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/1", data=user_info, headers=headers)
```

I've enabled logging and this is in Flask. If I manually do a POST request to the URL with the correct JSON response body, it works fine. It just says INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 0.0.0.0

And it just hangs there forever.

Any ideas?

Comment: The IP address `0.0.0.0` is used to signify an invalid IP. Maybe that's why it's hanging? Are you trying to reach localhost? If so, then use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead.

Comment: I just tried 127.0.0.1, it also hangs. Same with localhost.

Comment: What's the service that's handling port 5000?  Check if that service has any error output.

Comment: Sorry, how do I check what service is handling port 5000?

Comment: Kindly paste server side script also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your flask app with threading enabled.

`app.run(threaded=True)`

This is not advisable for production of course, just for quick development :)